# Github Advanced Security for Azure DevOps : CodeQL analyzer not working

Tags: azure-devops, codeql, github-advanced-security

Anyone has any experience with «GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps»?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/configure-github-advanced-security-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I configured everything as described. But I can't get the «Perform CodeQL analysis» working. and it's failing all the time for a simple hello world .net 6 c# app.
[image]
I tried with existing with existing c#-repo, and created a new repo, but still getting the same error.

The «Dependency scanning» on the other hand works as expected on the c#-repo. So the configuration isn't that wrong...

So: anyone any idea? Or got that thing up and running? Or has a example repo which should trigger the alerts?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's a Microsoft video [implementing GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rdlo33QYvXk), maybe it helps.

Comment: Can you trigger the alerts by following the steps mentioned in below answer?

Answer (score 2):

Find an example repo here: [ghas-demo](https://github.com/joshjohanning/ghas-demo) designed for GitHub workflows. However, it also applies to Azure DevOps.

Just import the repo to DevOps, then create a Yaml pipeline by following the steps mentioned in [Configure GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/configure-github-advanced-security-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-up-code-scanning)

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
  inputs:
    languages: 'java'

- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Autobuild@1

- task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1

- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1
```

Check for the alerts after the pipeline completion.

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. I noticed in my test that `- task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1` should come after the build.

Answer (score 0):

> csharp-security-extended.qls is not a .ql file, .qls file, a directory, or a query pack specification.

For self hosted machines, ensure that you follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/configure-github-advanced-security-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#extra-prerequisites-for-self-hosted-agents) to install the CodeQL bundle.  If you happened to just install the CodeQL CLI without the bundle then the query packs are not downloaded/installed. Otherwise, make sure the build service account has Read / Write / Execute permissions to this folder.